# Why do these functions give the correct output 75% of the time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

(this function is part of a larger program but operates independently of other functions.)

Ok I have a function jacket and given 3 inputs it produces the correct output only 75% of the time.

I do not know the inputs but I know the output is wrong.

I do not know what is wrong and have no idea how to fix it.

I assume it is the same 12 values entered each time the function is submitted to myProgrammingLab.

So it may be a problem with a specific input.

Thanks.

## The Description:

Jacket size (chest in inches) = height times weight divided by 288 and then adjusted by adding 1/8 of an inch for each 10 years over age 30. (note that the adjustment only takes place after a full 10 years. So, there is no adjustment for ages 30 through 39, but 1/8 of an inch is added for age 40.)

---

edit: changing tmp to float still produced the error.

```
 float jacket(float weight, float height, int age) {
        double result = (height * weight) / 288;
        /*now for every 10 years past 30 add (1/8) to the result*/
        if((age - 30) > 0){
            int temp = (age - 30) / 10;
            result = result + (temp * .125);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is the same function written differently with the same problem.

```
float jacket(double jWeight, double jHeight, int jAge)
{
    double jSize = ((jWeight*jHeight)/288.0);

    int i = jAge/10 - 3;

    if((jAge/10)>3)
        jSize += 0.125*i;
    
    return jSize;
}
```

This is a third function with the same problem

```
float  jacket(double weight, double height, int age)    

// calculates the jacket size, adjusting for age in increments
// of ten years, if customer is over 30 years of age.
{
    int age_factor;
    double j_size; 
    j_size = (height*weight)/288.0;
    if (age >=30) 
    {
    age_factor = (age-30)/10; //note possible truncation.
    j_size += age_factor/8.0;
    }
    return j_size;
}
```

The first time the function is called it produces an incorrect return value. the remain 3 times it is called the return value is correct.

Observe:

```
Expected Output:

jacket·size·=·24.17↵

jacket·size·=·40.00↵

jacket·size·=·46.04↵

jacket·size·=·35.42↵

Actual Output:

jacket·size·=·24.29↵

jacket·size·=·40.00↵

jacket·size·=·46.04↵

jacket·size·=·35.42↵
```

*All three functions given the same input produce the same output

Comment: You say you don't know the inputs? Could you give an example of the problem occurring with inputs and outputs that you *do* know?

Comment: Honestly I do not know what a correct input - > output looks like for these functions because there are no examples of them being used so I am not sure how I could replicate that. I'll try to recreate the problem.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Need to see the whole question in case something was missed. Really suck to turn over the assignment sheet and find "And take back one Kadan, to honor the Hebrew God whose jacket this is." written on the back.

Comment: Ok I'll post the part of the question this is about.

Comment: The difference between 24.29 and 24.17 is .12 which is suspiciously close to the  .125 factor being used in the math, and could be from the displayed values being rounded/truncated. So that implies an age is being classified into the wrong bracket. But... I'm not seeing a discrepancy between your algorithms and the description. That makes me wonder if the test case itself is defective. However without being able to see the inputs, that's rather hard to prove...

Comment: I know right. This is kind of insane. :(

Comment: Everything looks good. Just ran your code through ages 0-99 with height and width 0.0 and got what I'd expect. The difference isn't extreme enough for max int roll-over. Might be floating point fuzz from some dude a zillion feet tall and a micron wide, but if the inputs are sane, I'm stumped.

Comment: Not that it should make one whit of a difference in your output, but you can replace `if (age >= 30)` with `if (age >= 40)`, since it's only age 40 and up where the first size adjustment starts.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I agree.  It seems there is no consistent definition according to the code. e.g., age =30 "no adjustemnt", age = 40 "adjustment", so how about age =20 behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one *could* say that 31 isn't necessarily 1 year over 30. Try `int temp = (age - 31)/10;`.  Personally I think that's wrong, as does everyone else here, but someone could argue that the moment one turns 31 one is only a few seconds over 30. It's worth a try, anyway.

Comment: YOU HAVE SAVED ME. All hail Edward our new overlord. It worked :)

Comment: Nice to know that this generates the "right" answer, but how is this consistent with the instructions that say that 1/8 inch should be added for age 40?

Comment: I have no idea. I am submitting a ticket to them.

Comment: Welp, everyone's allowed a bug every now and again.

Answer (score 1):

```
int temp = (age - 30) / 10;
```

By making temp an `int`, you will get incorrect results, because of truncation. Try using a `float` instead.

Comment: Ok i'll try that out.

Comment: Even after changing tmp to a float i still get the same error.

Comment: Actually, there is no way of knowing if this will give incorrect answers or not. The algorithm may require truncating to only use whole number of years and not fractional. The OP has not stated his problem statement sufficiently.

Comment: "for every 10 years past 30" - Seems like integer truncation does just fine.

Comment: the program I am submitting this to wants a specific output. it has to literally be exact. its throwing an error because the output is 24.29 and not 24.17 for one of the test cases. the other 3 runs pass.

Comment: (age-30)/10 is an integral expression, so it can only give whole-number results.  Try something like: const float temp = float(age-30)/10;

Comment: @ChristopherOicles - The problem instruction is "for every 10 years past 30", so it seems like whole number results is what's called for. In any case, if integer truncation is the problem, it would cause OP's code to generate a number too small, and it's coming out too large.