# Trying to calculate jacket, hat, and waist size for assignment. Output is "0x8049f64" instead of answer

Tags: c++

I'm getting some odd outputs when running this program. Any suggestions? Pardon the mess. Typed it up in a hurry. This is the guidelines for the assignment.

> Write a program that asks for the user’s height, weight, and age, and
> then computesclothing sizes according to the formulas:
>
> 1.Hat size = weight in pounds divided by height in inches and all multiplied by 2.9
>
> 2.Jacket size (chest in inches) = height times weight divided by 288 and then adjusted by adding 1/8 of an inch for each 10 years over the age of 30.  (Note that the adjustment only takes place after a full 10 years.  Thus, there is no adjustment for ages 30 through 39, but 1/8 of an inch is added for age 40.)
>
> 3.Waist in inches=weight divided by 5.7 and then adjusted by adding 1/10 of an inch for each 2 years over age 28.  (Note that the adjustment only takes place
> after a full 2 years.  Thus, there is no adjustment for age 29, but 1/10 of an inch is added for age 30.)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double hat(double,double);

double jacket(double,double,int);

double waist(double,double,int);

int main ()
{
double height, weight;
int age;
char answer;

cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);

do
{
cout<< "Enter the customer's height in inches: ";
cin>>height;
cout<< "Enter the customer's weight in pounds: ";
cin>>weight;
cout<< "Enter the customer's age: ";
cin>>age;
cout << cout<< "\tYour Hat size: " << cout << "\tYour Jacket size: "< cout << "\tYour Waist size: "<< cout<< "Would you like to continue (y/n)? ";
cin>>answer;
}while(toupper(answer) == 'Y');
return 0;
}

double hat(double weight ,double height)
{
return ((weight/height) * 2.9);
}

double jacket(double height,double weight,int age)
{ 
double size;
int j;
if (age>=30)
{
if((age % 10) !=0)
age = age-(age%10);
j= (age-30)/10;
size =((height * weight) / 288)+((1.0/8)*j);
}
else
size =((height * weight) / 288);
return size;
}

double waist(double height,double weight,int age)
{
double size2;
int k;
if(age >= 28)
{
if((age % 2) !=0)
age = age-(age%2);
k = (age-28)/2;
size2 = (weight/(5.7))+( (1.0/10)*k);
}
else 
size2 = weight / (5.7);
return size2;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code or something you typed out for SO, because there are some typos in it that would cause weird behavior.

Comment: By the way, all your calculations using modulo (`%`) are unneeded.  Integer division truncates.

Comment: It's my actual code unfortunately.

Comment: `k/10.0` will be better than `(1.0/10)*k`. And please indent your code properly

Comment: similar jacket size problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/31063332/995714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final cout << line in the do loop is piping cout to cout, instead of your answer to cout.  Not to mention there's a < in there after jacket size instead of a <<

```
cout << cout<< "\tYour Hat size: " << cout << "\tYour Jacket size: "< cout << "\tYour Waist size: "<< cout<< "Would you like to continue (y/n)? ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You never even tried to do the calculation, so you have no answer to print.

Instead I see a lot of `cout << cout` in your code.  Trying to print `cout` itself doesn't turn out well.  What happens is that iostreams don't know how to print an output stream, however in old versions of C++, `cout` has an implicit conversion to a pointer, and a stream knows how to display that.  So you are seeing the pointer equivalent to `cout`.

You should enable C++11 (or later) support in your compiler.  Then `cout` won't have an implicit conversion to `void*`, and the compiler will detect mistakes like this.

Comment: I currently just dev c++ for my compiler

Comment: @Jonathan there ar much better C++ compilers available for free.  G++ and clang are both very good. If you're on Windows then the free edition of MS Visual C++ is available as well.  All of these have many fewer bugs and much better compiler messages than Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace your `cout` line with this line of code

```
cout<< "\tYour Hat size: " << hat(weight ,height) << "\tYour Jacket size: "<< jacket( height, weight, age) << "\tYour Waist size: "<< waist( height, weight, age)<< "\n \nWould you like to continue (y/n)? ";
```